# Word for missing out/losing someone's employeeship

Tags: single-word-requests

If you choose to leave a store/restaurant, you say *they lost your **business/service***. How would you say the same for employment? Take, for instance:

> The interview went great, yet they still did not hire me. I guess they lost my _______.

Would *employeeship* or *employment* be correct? Both of them sound rather odd in this context.

Comment: You could say "employment."  I can't think of anything better than that.  I would not say "employeeship" because that term is not a common term in English and is at best [a neologism meaning something completely different.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Employeeship)

Comment: If they thought not having you as an employee would be loss, they would have hired you.  Therefore it’s not a loss of anything to them.

Comment: contributions,  potential contribution

Comment: I think a better parallel to *loss of custom* would be something like *The company lost my ___ due to their toxic work environment and sub-standard compensation.* I actually think one of the words you suggested, ***service***, makes more sense for employees than customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you choose to leave a store/restaurant, you say they lost your
>   business/service.

In this example you have presented, you are referring to something you were offering them, which they lost out on. They could have had your business/service but they did not because you left.

So you need a word which describes the object/quality the employer has lost  by not employing you.

> The interview went great, yet they still did not hire me. I guess they
>   lost my talent.

However because they never had your talent in the first place I would adjust slightly to:

> The interview went great, yet they still did not hire me. I guess they
>   lost out on my talent.

Talent is a word frequently used in this context, take this plethora of examples, courtesy of Merriam-Webster:

***[Talent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/talent)***

> She has a job that makes the most of her talents.
>
> His experience, skills, and talents make him perfectly suited for the
>   job.
>
> There are many good players on the team, but she's a special talent.
>
> The company has hired some expensive legal talent for the trial.
>
> The team has recruited some of the best talent around.
>
> The company is doing a talent search to find the right person for the
>   job.

Answer (score 1):

"The interview went great, yet they still didn't hire me. I guess they lost **[confidence in]** my" *ability/potential to be an employee*.

I have gone beyond the OP by editing the original syntax and then adding *ability/potential to be an employee*. I hope that my syntactic suggestion is acceptable.

Comment: That's strange. I have attempted and failed to edit my answer by correcting my misspelling "poetntial" [sic].

Comment: I took care of it.